# When running tests with cypress got error 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null..' and tests fails

Tags: cypress

I'm running tests with cypress and getting an error

```
Cannot set property 'width' of null
TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null
at l
```

tried using wait but got the same result. I'm new to cypress and the web page is developed by someone else.

```
describe('Check kaiinPageTransit', function() {

context('Navigation', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://student-staging.xxx/#/')
    cy.contains('ログイン').click()

            cy.get('.is-mail > input').type(‘abc@miail.com’) 
            cy.get('.is-key > input').type('123qwerty')
            cy.get('.el-button').click()
            cy.get('.bl-mystatus-profile-name').contains('ひっでさん', { timeout: 10000 } )
    })
    it('check kaiinPageTransit', () => {

        //学習状況
        cy.contains('会員').click()
        cy.contains('学習状況').click()
        cy.contains('最近よく学習している科目’)

        //ブックマーク
        cy.contains('会員').click()
        cy.contains('ブックマーク').click()
        cy.contains(‘まだブックマークありません’)

        //視聴履歴
        cy.contains('会員').click()
        cy.contains('視聴履歴').click()
        cy.contains(‘まだ視聴履歴ありません’）

    })

})
```

})

Comment: Can you please add the cypress test that you are running.

Comment: @soccerway Added the test. It is just clicking buttons on the home page and check if the page opens correctly.

Comment: Also can you please add full details of error from console, screenshot of the steps where its failing from the test runner, it will be more helpful to give a peep. Also share the url if possible..

Comment: @soccerway Is there any way I could send these to you on a private channel? This is a customer project and my manager doesn't like screenshots to appear on the internet. :(

Comment: Is it possible to share the url that you are testing?

Comment: @soccerway url: https://student.try-it.jp/#/  id: chanya.deshani@gmail.com pw: 12345678

Comment: Chanya Deshani, I have provided my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cypress test, there are a few lines you have added wrong quotes, for example, `cy.contains(‘まだ視聴履歴ありません’)`, you have to use single quotes `''` in cypress. I have seen Cypress face problem while using the following symbol `‘`. The next thing, I assume that you are testing for navigation tabs. Then may I ask you, why do you need to click this tab `cy.contains('会員').click()` repeatedly? You are still on that page right so can access another navigation tab without that extra click. I have removed those clicks and refactored the test as below, it runs successfully here, please refer the screenshot below; On click on this `ブックマーク` navigation tab, for example `cy.contains('ブックマーク').click()` you have missed some `symbols and space` at the end of your assertion/contains step, like this one `。`, the same for this tab `視聴履歴'` .I have updated for those test steps here.

```
describe('Check kaiinPageTransit', function() {
  context('Navigation', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('https://student.try-it.jp/#/')
      cy.contains('ログイン').click()

              cy.get('.is-mail > input').type('chanya.deshani@gmail.com') 
              cy.get('.is-key > input').type('12345678')
              cy.get('.el-button').click()
              cy.get('.bl-mystatus-profile-name').contains('さん', { timeout: 10000 } )
      })
      it.only('check kaiinPageTransit', () => {

          //学習状況
         cy.contains('会員').click()
         cy.contains('学習状況').click()
         cy.contains('最近よく学習している科目')


          //ブックマーク        
         cy.contains('ブックマーク').click()
         cy.get('.bl-container>p').invoke('text')       
            .then((text) => {
              const txt = text;
              expect(txt).to.equal('まだブックマークがありません。');

            })

          //視聴履歴
          cy.contains('視聴履歴').click()
          cy.get('.bl-container>p').invoke('text')       
            .then((text) => {
              const txt = text;
              expect(txt).to.equal('まだ視聴履歴がありません。');

            })

      })

  })
  })
```

[image]